# unable to view pods in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am unable to list my pod (kubectl get pods) after creating it.

```
kubectl apply -f my-config.yml
```

returns me this log below,

configmap "my-config" deleted

daemonset "my" deleted

service "my" deleted

configmap "my-config" created

daemonset "my" created

service "my" created

And the command (`kubectl get pods`) doesn't list the pod created!

Below is the config file I have used,

```
# runs linkerd in a daemonset, in linker-to-linker mode
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: l5d-config
data:
  config.yaml: |-
    admin:
      port: 9990

    namers:
    - kind: io.l5d.k8s
      experimental: true
      host: localhost
      port: 8001

    telemetry:
    - kind: io.l5d.prometheus
    - kind: io.l5d.recentRequests
      sampleRate: 0.25

    usage:
      orgId: linkerd-examples-daemonset

    routers:
    - protocol: http
      label: outgoing
      dtab: |
        /srv        => /#/io.l5d.k8s/default/http;
        /host       => /srv;
        /svc        => /host;
        /host/world => /srv/world-v1;
      interpreter:
        kind: default
        transformers:
        - kind: io.l5d.k8s.daemonset
          namespace: default
          port: incoming
          service: l5d
      servers:
      - port: 4140
        ip: 0.0.0.0
      service:
        responseClassifier:
          kind: io.l5d.http.retryableRead5XX

    - protocol: http
      label: incoming
      dtab: |
        /srv        => /#/io.l5d.k8s/default/http;
        /host       => /srv;
        /svc        => /host;
        /host/world => /srv/world-v1;
      interpreter:
        kind: default
        transformers:
        - kind: io.l5d.k8s.localnode
      servers:
      - port: 4141
        ip: 0.0.0.0
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: l5d
  name: l5d
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: l5d
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: l5d-config
        configMap:
          name: "l5d-config"
      containers:
      - name: l5d
        image: buoyantio/linkerd:1.0.0
        env:
        - name: POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        args:
        - /io.buoyant/linkerd/config/config.yaml
        ports:
        - name: outgoing
          containerPort: 4140
          hostPort: 4140
        - name: incoming
          containerPort: 4141
        - name: admin
          containerPort: 9990
        volumeMounts:
        - name: "l5d-config"
          mountPath: "/io.buoyant/linkerd/config"
          readOnly: true

      - name: kubectl
        image: buoyantio/kubectl:v1.4.0
        args:
        - "proxy"
        - "-p"
        - "8001"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: l5d
spec:
  selector:
    app: l5d
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: outgoing
    port: 4140
  - name: incoming
    port: 4141
  - name: admin
    port: 9990
```

Comment: Please share the contents of your `my-config.yml`, especially of the `"my"` daemon set.

Comment: @helmbert added the config, also I am able to get the pod running on different cluster with the same config

Comment: Please share the output of `kubectl describe daemonset my` to see why the daemonset hasn't created any nodes, also `kubectl get nodes` would be useful, to check taints, and etc...

Comment: @NandorKracser I was able to resolve this, there is a pod with the same name in a different namespace, deleting that resolved the issue, but I thought pod with the same name can exist in two different namespaces

Comment: Note that I was deploying it as daemonset, so was the conflict

Comment: That would do it... Thanks for calling out the solution to help us all look for similar stuff in the future.